# Unnormalizing in Knuth's Algorithm D

Tags: division, knuth, euclidean-algorithm

I'm trying to implement Algorithm D from Knuth's "**The Art of Computer Programming, Vol 2**" in Rust although I'm having trouble understating how to implement the very last step of unnormalizing. My natural numbers are a class where each number is a vector of u64, in base `u64::MAX`. Addition, subtraction, and multiplication have been implemented.

Knuth's Algorithm D is a euclidean division algorithm which takes two natural numbers `x` and `y` and returns `(q,r)` where `q = x / y` (integer division) and `r = x % y`, the remainder. The algorithm depends on an approximation method which only works if the first digit of `y` is greater than `b/2`, where `b` is the base you're representing the numbers in. Since not all numbers are of this form, it uses a "*normalizing trick*", for example (if we were in base 10) instead of doing `200 / 23`, we calculate a normalizer `d` and do `(200 * d) / (23 * d)` so that `23 * d` has a first digit greater than `b/2`.

So when we use the approximation method, we end up with the desired q but the remainder is multiplied by a factor of `d`. So the last step is to divide `r` by `d` so that we can get the `q` and `r` we want. My problem is, I'm a bit confused at how we're suppose to do this last step as it **requires** division and the method it's part of is trying to implement division.

**(Maybe helpful?):**
The way that `d` is calculated is just by taking the integer floor of `b-1` divided by the first digit of y. However, Knuth suggests that it's possible to make `d` a power of 2, as long as `d *` the first digit of y is greater than `b / 2`. I think he makes this suggestion so that instead of dividing, we can just do a binary shift for this last step. Although I don't think I can do that given that my numbers are represented as vectors of `u64` values, instead of binary.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this question is Rust related, so I'd remove the `rust` tag.

Comment: What do you want to be suggested to you?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you should pick `d` as a power of two. You need just a shift: `shift = count_leading_zeroes(divisor[divisor.size() - 1])`.
Then, instead of multiplying and dividing, you can shift your big integers.
Here is an example code for shifting big integers:

```cpp
// For base = 2^64 and 0 <= shift <= 64
void shift_right_inplace(bint_t& a, int shift) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.data.size(); i++) {
        const uint64_t self = a.data[i] >> shift;
        const uint64_t prev = i == a.data.size() - 1 ? 0 : a.data[i + 1] << (64 - shift);
        a.data[i] = self | prev;
    }
    if (a.data.back() == 0) {
        a.data.pop_back();
    }
}
```

For example, let's take base as 256 for simplicity and look at two adjacent "digits": `abcdefgh` and `klmnopqr`. You want to shift it right by 3.

The first byte has no neighbor from the left, so you just shift it: `000abcde`. For the second byte, you shift it (`000klmno`) and take the rest from the previous byte (`abcdefgh >> 3 = 000abcde | fgh`, it is effectively `prev << (8 - 3)`).